# How much to increase $A$ so that $B$ becomes $90\%$ of what is was?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

If I had a mixture of $A$ and $B$, and I wanted to increase $A$ so that $B$ drops to $90\%$ of what it was in the solution -- how would I solve this?

For example, say $A$ was $90$ grams ($90\%$) and $B$ was $10$ grams ($10\%$) for a total of $100$ grams. By how much I increase the weight of $A$ so that $B$ becomes $9\%$?

Comment: Try to give a suitable equation to solve. How do you calculate the ratio in general? How do you express "Increasing the weight of $A$" mathematically?

Comment: If you add some weight $A^+$ to the mix, then $9\%$ of the total mixture is 
$$
(A +B + A^+)(0.09)
$$
Since you want this $9\%$ to be equal to $B$, can you set up an equation that'll allow you to solve for $A^+$?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{B}{A+B+k} = .9 \times \frac{B}{A+B}.$  Solve for $(k)$, which is the amount added, in terms of $A,B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B is $10$% of the mixture, we can say that the ratio of $\frac{B}{A+B} =0.1$

Relative to your example, to solve for the increase in A such that B becomes $9$ percent of the solution, whilst the amount of $B$ remains at $10$ grams we input:

$\frac{B}{A+B} = 0.09$

$\frac{10}{A+10} = 0.09$

$A = \frac{10}{0.09} - 10$

$A = \frac{1000}{9} - \frac{90}{9}$

$A = \frac{910}{9}$

Furthermore, if we want to solve for the change in A we can compute:

$\Delta A = A_{final} - A_{initial}$

$\Delta A = \frac{910}{9} - 90$

$\Delta A = \frac{100}{9}$

Comment: 90%, not 9%. Also, not 90% of the solution, but 90% of the original value of B.

Comment: @MathNewbie You explicitly state in your question "say A was 90 grams (90%) and B was 10 grams (10%) for a total of 100 grams. By how much I increase the weight of A so that B becomes 9%?" What you say now is different to the question that you asked....

Comment: Say B was 10 grams, which represented 10% of the solution. We need to increase the amount of A such that B becomes 90% of it's original 10% ... which is 9% of the total mixture.

Comment: @MathNewbie Yes... that is what I solved for, so that B is now 9% of the total mixture...